# Nesting generator expression calling a dynamically referenced function

Tags: python, generator-expression

I'm seeing some really odd behavior that I am not sure how to explain, when dynamically nesting generator expressions in Python 3, when the generator expression references a function which is dynamically referenced.

Here is a very simplified case reproducing the problem:

```py
double = lambda x: x * 2
triple = lambda x: x * 3
processors = [double, triple]

data = range(3)
for proc in processors:
    data = (proc(i) for i in data)

result = list(data)
print(result)
assert result == [0, 6, 12]
```

In this case, I expected each number to be multiplied by 6 (`triple(double(x))`) but in reality `triple(triple(x))` is called. It's more or less clear to me that `proc` points to `triple` when the generator expression is run, regardless of what it pointed to when the generator expression was created.

So, (1) is this expected and can someone point to some relevant info in the Python docs or elsewhere explaining this?

and (2) Can you recommend another method of nesting generator expressions, where each level calls a dynamically provided callable?

EDIT: I am seeing it on Python 3.8.x, haven't tested with other versions

Comment: Those first two lines could be `def` statements and still be one-liners: `def double(x): return x * 2` (all on one line). Then you get the advantage of the function having a name (which helps when interpreting error messages), not to mention it's just more idiomatic. Lambdas exist for generating functions inline, right where you're using them. If you're assigning it to a variable anyway, you're [better off making it a proper function definition](https://treyhunner.com/2018/09/stop-writing-lambda-expressions/#Misuse:_naming_lambda_expressions).

Comment: @CrazyChucky good point, totally agree. I used lambdas only in this example, my real code uses actual named functions.

Answer (score 2):

This is a result of two things:

- Generators are lazily evaluated, so the functions are only called when the generator is consumed,
- Names are resolved at evaluation time, not when the generator is created.

So at the time you consume the generator with `list(data)`, the name `proc` refers to the function `triple`, and both generators call the function bound by the name `proc`, so you get `triple` twice.

The reason `map` works is because it's a function, so when you pass `proc` as an argument, it receives the value of `proc` at the time `map` is called, which is in the loop while `proc` still can refer to the `double` function.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's expected, and you got the reason right.

As generators are lazy, `proc(i)` gets evaluated only when requested. Which involves evaluating `proc` and `i` then. And when you finally do request, `proc` is already `triple`, so that's what gets used.

In this particular case, `data = map(proc, data)` does the job. It works because `map` captures and remembers the `proc` as it was when you called `map`.

You could do the same with a generator *function*. I tried with a generator *expression* like

```
data = (p(i) for p in [proc] for i in data)
```

but it failed with `ValueError: generator already executing`. This worked, though:

```
data = (lambda proc: (proc(i) for i in data))(proc)
```

Answer (score 2):

This does not works because `proc` is reasigned to `triple` in the second iteration of the loop, which changes the `proc` reference of the first iteration. This is more explicit by un-rolling the loop and removing the last generator:

```py
double = lambda x: x * 2
triple = lambda y: y * 3

data = range(3)
proc = double
data = (proc(i) for i in data)

# Let's change `proc` to be triple
proc = triple

result = list(data)
print(result)
# [0, 3, 6]
```

The data as been tripled, which means that by reassigning proc to be `triple` you changes the value behind the reference in the first generator.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that using `map` *does* work, which is a good answer for #2 as far as I'm concerned:

```py
double = lambda x: print(x) or x * 2
triple = lambda x: print(x) or x * 3
processors = [double, triple]

data = range(3)
for proc in processors:
    data = map(proc, data)

result = list(data)
print(result)
assert result == [0, 6, 12]
```

Still, I'd be happy to know about #1 - what is the reason for this behavior and is this documented somewhere?